# Fabric.io implementation (AppDelegate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fabric.io

I'm trying to implement Fabric into my app. The problem is, that the app isn't working correctly and I have no idea what code to place in my AppDelegate. I can't find any information on the web what should I implement there. Can anyone give me a tip, what functions should I implement in my AppDelegate?

[image: Fabric screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you used the build script to setup Fabric, it will have placed the appropriate `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` in your project's info.plist.

You can initialize Fabric with this method:

Swift

```
Fabric.with(Twitter(), Crashlytics()) // Add whichever Kits you are using
```

ObjectiveC

```
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]] // Add whichever Kits you are using
```

Double check that your plist contains an entry for Fabric and add this line of code to your `application:didFinishingLaunchWithOptions:` method.

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/configure

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use Crashlytics with Objective-C?

In your AppDelegate.m:

At the top of the source file,

```
#import "Fabric/Fabric.h"
#import "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h"
```

and in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`,

```
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

Comment: this is more clean to do <Fabric/Fabric.h> instead of "Fabric/Fabric.h" for every framework

Answer (score 1):

For swift the missing code is:

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
        //... your initialization code
        return true
    }
```

Comment: @Vive Yes, but it is correct for the last version: Fabric.with accepts arrays